# Improve the Look & Feel of a disabled CheckBox

Tags: java, jcheckbox

There are set of check boxes and I select them in my program as required. Since I just need to display selected values, user should not be able to do actions on these check boxes.(i.e. selecting check boxes). Disabling these check boxes(i.e. setEnabled(false)), gives it a odd look by greying it out. Is there a solution exists without disabling combo boxes? I tried consume() for the ActionEvent. But using consume() is not possible.

Comment: So, are you asking how to disable a checkbox without greying it out?

Comment: I suppose you could extend JCheckBox or whatever check box you are using and override the setEnabled() method...